# DATE_FORMAT() sql return 0 rows

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a table with the following fields:

```
themeID = int(11)  
partnerID = int(11)  
name = varchar(255)  
BeginDate = date (Y-m-d)  
EndDate = date (Y-m-d)  
active = tinyint(1)
```

I want to select the theme that has the BeginDate before `01-30`, and the EndDate after `01-30`.
I just want to search on the month and the day and **not** on the year.

I use the following Query, but I get nothing back(0 rows):

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(BeginDate, '%m-%d'),
  DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%m-%d')
FROM theme
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(BeginDate, '%m-%d') <= '01-30'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%m-%d') > '01-30'
ORDER BY BeginDate
```

What did I do wrong?

PS. there are record that start before now(01-30) and end after now(01-30)

**EDIT**
Table Data

```
Default ...... 2000-01-01 ... 2000-01-01  
Oud en Nieuw . 2000-12-26 ... 2000-01-04  
Pasen ........ 2000-03-28 ... 2000-04-04  
Dierendag..... 2000-10-04 ... 2000-10-04  
Sinterklaas .. 2000-11-20 ... 2000-12-05  
Kerstmis ..... 2000-12-23 ... 2000-12-26  
Winter ....... 2000-12-21 ... 2000-03-20
```

Comment: do you have records before and after these dates?

Comment: i have tested the query and there is no problem. You might have not records in the database table

Comment: there are no records that start before now and end after now in your sample data... maybe you need to check also records that started the year before, and end later this year?

Comment: @fthiella When i use 3 for month and 29 for day then i should get back  'Pasen' right?

Comment: @GertKommer yes... but it already works... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a36b2/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can probably be optimized, this converts all dates to the same year (2000) and compares accordingly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT themeID, name,
      DATE_FORMAT(BeginDate, '%m-%d'), 
      DATE_FORMAT(EndDate, '%m-%d'),
      DATE(BeginDate + INTERVAL (2000 - Extract(YEAR from BeginDate)) YEAR) NewBeginDate,
      DATE(EndDate + INTERVAL (2000 - Extract(YEAR from EndDate)) YEAR) NewEndDate
FROM theme
) a
WHERE NewBeginDate <= DATE(Now() + INTERVAL (2000 - Extract(YEAR from Now())) YEAR)
  AND NewEndDate > DATE(Now() + INTERVAL (2000 - Extract(YEAR from Now())) YEAR)
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5958/58).

With that said, you're query seems to work just fine for me.  Try your own query in the Fiddle above.

Good luck.

Comment: This is doing what is was looking for, but is it really nessecery to change the year??

Comment: Well, your query seemed to work for me too :-) -- this is just something I've used in the past successfully.  Here is the Fiddle with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5958/59

Comment: I see now... i think the problem was that i had no event on the current date so it didn't select a theme. shame on me.. still thx for the alternative way to select the right theme. works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
... WHERE (MONTH(BeginDate) <= 1 AND DAY(BeginDate) < 30)
        AND (MONTH(EndDate) >= 1 AND DAY(EndDate) > 30)
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5958/1)

Comment: for January it's not a problem, but I would use `(MONTH(BeginDate) < 1 OR (MONTH(BeginDate)=1 AND DAY(BeginDate) < 30))` which is more general

Comment: i tried your code, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Returns 0 rows

Comment: @GertKommer I think we need to re-evaluate the desired result here. Could you provide what your sample data should return?

Comment: I want that the current theme is selected by using the datetimes .
example:
if the date is 11-25 then the `sinterklaas` theme should be the row that is returned.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that you want it based off the current date :) Give me a few moments.

Comment: @GertKommer [Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a36b2/10) what I've done so far. I want to clarify, you have some themes that would fall under multiple ranges (Winter & Oud en Nieuw). How do you want those handled?

Comment: sorry for not being clear on the current date issue. about the double events. there is a field `active` in the tbl and the idea is to say that when active is 1 it selects that theme. so when it is christmas i set the christmas theme to 1. something like that. haven't figured it out really:) Thx for the support on my question. i've tryed yours as well and works great too:)